# How to pass current user to server upon a POST request?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

I am submitting a form to a POST route and was wondering how I can pass the current user to the POST request.

Comment: Can you share some code showing what you are doing?  Are you using one of the parse language SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Initiate an ajax call with the data of current user after loading the